# Create an Open stack Instance or Image from .VMDK file in a volume

Tags: openstack, openstack-glance

I have a bootable raw Volume (myVolume1) with .VMDK file in it.
myVolume1 in not mounted to any instance.

I would like to create an Instance or an Image from this .VMDK file.

I already try to create an Instance from myVolume1 but it say OS not found.

Is it possible to create an Instance or an Image from .vmdk file sitting in a volume?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the image and then import it to openstaack and use it.

Run the following command to convert a vmdk image file to a raw image file:

```
$ qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O raw image.vmdk image.img
```

OR

Run the following command to convert a vmdk image file to a qcow2 image file:

```
$qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O qcow2 image.vmdk image.qcow2
```

See [Covert images](http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html)